# How to count the number of <li>'s produced by a dynamic list and apply styles according to that number

Tags: php, jquery

I'm building a website for an artist that needs to be able to post either a statement, gallery, video, or poetry content.

I have a list of tab-able content that is generated based on wether not that there is content in that category (ex: the statement tab exists only when there's statement content, same for video, same for gallery, same for poetry.)

What I need to do is dynamically add in a little CSS snippet based on how many items are the in tab list because the site is responsive.

When all four categories exist, they are 25% width of the container.

What I would like is to use PHP to find out how many list items long that list is for that page and, say if there are 3 list items I would like their width to be 33.3% of the container.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Here is the list HTML

```
<ul class="jquery-tabs">

<?php if ( $statementTrue == true ) : ?>
    <li><a class="statement-tab" href="#statement-tab">statement</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( $galleryTrue == true ) : ?>
    <li><a class="gallery-tab" href="#gallery-tab">gallery</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( $videoTrue == true ) : ?>
    <li><a class="video-tab" href="#video-tab">video</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( $poetryTrue == true ) : ?>
    <li><a class="poetry-tab" href="#poetry-tab">poetry</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: Why not use jquery? $("li").length or size()

Comment: @mplungjan He wants to to it with PHP... So i don't understand its needs...

atotalpirate Please edit your post.

Comment: <? $cnt=0; if .... $cnt++;   ?><li...

Comment: That's PHP, that *generates* HTML. But basically, mplungjan's comment is the correct answer.

Comment: David Thomas, that makes sense. I was trying to do something like `foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('ul.jquery-tabs') as $ul) {
 
    $count = $ul->getElementsByTagName('li')->length;
 
 };` and then `if ($count == 3){echo "<style>.jquery-tabs li {width:33.3%;}</style>"};`

Comment: Btw, you can shorten `if ( $statementTrue == true )` to just `if ( $statementTrue )`, the `== true` part is redundant.

Comment: TiiJ7, Thanks! I'm trying to get more comfortable in PHP and these are the kind of things I need to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
var lis = $('ul.jquery-tabs li');
lis.css('width', (100/lis.length) + '%');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XERCQ/1/).

This does require that the `li` elements are floated, in order that the white-space in the HTML doesn't cause spacing between the `li` elements.

References:

- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Comment: Thank you Michael Boska, raj, David Thomas your answers are all helpful and even though I'll only use one solution I'll be better equipped to tackle similar problems in the future with better options!

Comment: @David, perhaps `parseInt(100/lis.length,10)` and a `text-align:center;`?

Answer (score 0):

You can count child elements with jQuery: $("ul.jquery-tabs li").size()

EDIT: Sorry, that's on Client side. On the server side, I would probably do something like this:

```
  <ul class="jquery-tabs">
    <?php $count = 0; ?>
    <?php if ( $statementTrue == true ) {
      $count++;
     ?>
        <li><a class="statement-tab" href="#statement-tab">statement</a></li>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if ( $galleryTrue == true ) {
      $count++; ?>
        <li><a class="gallery-tab" href="#gallery-tab">gallery</a></li>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if ( $videoTrue == true ) {
       $count++;?>
        <li><a class="video-tab" href="#video-tab">video</a></li>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if ( $poetryTrue == true ) { 
      $count++; ?>
        <li><a class="poetry-tab" href="#poetry-tab">poetry</a></li>
    <?php } ?>

</ul>
```

At the end, the `$count` variable will contain number of displayed elements.

Comment: I feel dumb for not trying this first. Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: This worked like a charm. I think the jQuery solution would be less code and more elegant though. Thanks again for your expertise!